# Is it OK to put sod on top of gravel?

Tags: lawn, soil, grass, soil-amendment, sod

I have a small area (approx 400 sqft) near the pool where I'm looking to put down sod.  I ordered the sod to be delivered today.  Yesterday I used a mini tiller to loosen the dirt.  I found that under the dirt was gravel.  See pictures.  Is it ok to put the sod on top of that?  What should I do?  thanks

[image: section1]

[image: section2]

Comment: Good question; if could include region, type of sod intended, soil, depth of soil, depth of soil between concrete & fence, depth of underlying gravel, if sunlit area or shaded area, and if intend watering, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Region - Rockland County NY (about 45 min north of NYC)  The gravel seems to be a thin layer.  re: sun - gets about 4 horus of sunlihgt/day.  dept of dirt seems pretty deep

Comment: Thank you for including very helpful additional information. You can also add additional text and illustrations to your questions and answers by clicking on the 'edit' link at the lower left of of your questions and answers. Thank you! Welcome to the site!